# Neo4j Traversal PathEvaluator BranchState set to null

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, traversal, graph-databases

I'm trying to use TraversalDescription to traverse a graph. For my purpose it's necessary to implement PathEvaluator with customized evalute(Path, BranchState) method implementation. which I have done by creating a new class called CustomPathEvaluator implementing PathEvaluator.

My problem is that when I initial BranchState in the traversal and set a State to it I cannot recover the state at the next child. That means the BranchState is set to null.
So here is my simplified code:

```
public class CustomPathEvaluator implements PathEvaluator<StateInfo> {

    private Node endNode;

    public Evaluation evaluate(Path path, BranchState<StateInfo> branchState) {

        Node node = path.endNode();

        if(path.length() == 0) {

            StateInfo stateInfo = new StateInfo();
            stateInfo.label = 2;


            InitialBranchState.State<StateInfo> si
                         = new State<StateInfo>(stateInfo, null);

            branchState.setState(si.initialState(path));

            if(node.getId() == endNode.getId()) {
                return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
            }
            else {
                return Evaluation.Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
            }
        }


        int oldLabel = branchState.getState().label;
        // DO something with the old label

        if(node.getId() == endNode.getId()) {
            return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
        }
        else {
            return Evaluation.ofContinues(true); //EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
        }

    }
}
```

Here in this code I get a NullPointerException when I call

```
  int oldLabel = branchState.getState().label;
```

I use TraversalDescription as follows:

```
        CustomPathEvaluator eval = new CustomPathEvaluator(endNode);

        TraversalDescription desc = graphDb.traversalDescription()
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_PATH)
                .sort(new Comparator<Path>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Path o1, Path o2) {
                        return o1.length() - o2.length();
                    }
                })
                .evaluator(eval)
                .breadthFirst()
                .relationships(EdgeType.LINE_REL, Direction.OUTGOING)
                .relationships(EdgeType.STATION_REL, Direction.OUTGOING)
                .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(maxDepth));

        for (Path path : desc.traverse(node1)) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
```

Am I using BranchState wrong? How can I get the stateInfo from previous step?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: I think I have traced it down to StartNodeTraversalBranch.newNextBranch where the state gets lost if the initialState == InitialBranchState.NO_STATE. For me this is always the case as the framework initializes it in MonoDirectionalTraversalDescription. I am trying to find out if this is a bug or how to work around on that on the neo4j Slack.

Comment: Max de Marzi pointed me to his blog entry https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/11/20/bidirectional-traversals-in-space/ where he explains how to solve the problem using a PathExpander instead of a PathEvaluator. This worked out for me even though I still do not understand why the PathEvaluator does not work as expected.